# Obter dados de cada key do firebase com javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

Tenho os seguintes registro no firebase:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E estou tentando obter os valores "female", "male" e "mixed" de cada registro e no caso se ele for "true" eu marco uma checkbox, porém aparentemente meu código não esta validando registro por registro e sim todos de uma unica vez

Meu código (Ainda não implementei todas as condições estou testando apenas com uma):

```js
    var db = firebase.database().ref("modality");
    db.once("value", function(snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach(function(child){

        if ( child.val().female == "true" ){
          inputModalityFemale.checked = true;
        } else {
          inputModalityFemale.checked = false;
        }
        console.log(child.val().mixed);
        
      });
    });
```

Alguem teria alguma dica?

Answer (score 0):

A resposta que vc recebe na variavel "snapshot" não são os dados que vêm do seu database.
Para que você tenha acesso aos dados, você tem que executar a função ".val()" na resposta do firebase.
Sendo assim, segue as alterações:

```
var db = firebase.database().ref("modality");
    db.once("value", function(snapshot){
      snapshot.val().forEach(function(child){

        if ( child.female == "true" ){
          inputModalityFemale.checked = true;
        } else {
          inputModalityFemale.checked = false;
        }
        console.log(child.mixed);

      });
    });
```

Ao executar a função ".val()" na resposta, aí sim vc tem o array para ser usado na iteração.

Comment: Neste casso utilizando a sua sugestão eu obtive : Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.val(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: se vc der console.log() em snapshot.val(), o que aparece aí no console?

Comment: logger.ts:84 [2019-05-26T13:25:57.238Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: snapshot.val(...).forEach is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: snapshot.val(...).forEach is not a function